# Splitting a Array in Android

Tags: android

I get the text from textfield and stores it in a string array. I want to split these by space. How can i do that?

This is my code

```
et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
String[] textarray = {et.getText().toString()};
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try split() of String class?

Comment: Ya i tried that but not working with array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the original string though like this:

```
String[] textArray = et.getText().toString().split(' ');
```

That will return a String array

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
String s = et.getText().toString();
String[] split =  s.split(" ");

for(int i =0; i < split.length; i++)
{
   String[] textarray = {split[i]};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

String[] result = textarray .split("\\s+");